# Send custom variables to Google Analytics for differentiating new and re-downloads

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

I have a software download website, People can download software only by creating an account on my website...

I have enabled my e-commerce option in Google Analytics, and I am recording the download transaction to the e-commerce. All transactions are being recorded...

Now, I want to know that a software is downloaded by a new member or an existing member, I want to see this on Google analytics\ e-commerce..

Any Ideas Please...?

Comment: [webmasters.se] would probably be a better place to ask this but check their help centre before you post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to differentiate between users who are subscribers and guests to your websites. This can be done by assigning a custom dimension. Implementation differs and depends on whether you use the new universal Analytics version of GA or the old version. 
To point you in the right direction, if you are using the new version:

1. Go to the admin => Property settings => Custom dimensions
2. Define a new custom dimension, call it 'User Status' for example
3. Define the scope of the parameter. Now, this part really depends on the logic behind your service. One possibility is to choose a 'session' scope, and update GA once the user becomes a registered user/logs in.
4. Implement the code: (this is an example for the registered user)

   ```
   var dimensionValue = 'Registered User';
   ga('set', 'dimension1', dimensionValue);
   ```
5. After implementation, you will be able to create a custom report. Again, it depends on your version of the GA code, but if you are on Universal, go to the customization tab, and create a new report there, where data is either segmented or sliced according to the new dimension you have just created. Needless to say that this is only applicable for new data that was acquired after the implementation.

Custom Dimensions docs can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/customdimsmets).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Event Tracking provided by Google Analytics. Event Tracking is a method available in the ga.js tracking code that you can use to record user interaction with website elements,

For futher details you can   [Event Tracking provided by Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)

I hope this will help you to tracking things as per your customized way.